# Require authentication from subset of mynetworks in postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp

Is it possible to configure smtp for postfix to require authentication, (e.g. with `smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes`), for certain IP ranges but have other ranges un-authenticated?

For our local network we want hosts to be able to relay through the smtp servers without authentication, including sending externally. That network range is listed in `mynetworks`.

But for other ranges, not on our network but in `mynetworks`, it would be better to require authentication to smtp.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the documentation

> By default, Postfix will forward mail from clients in authorized network blocks to any destination. Authorized networks are defined with the `mynetworks` configuration parameter.

If you want to require auth for some networks you need to remove them from `mynetworks`. You'll need to enable relaying for SASL authenticated clients with `permit_sasl_authenticated`.